# Could you please help me understand the error log?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone,
I am completely new to ROS or any distribution computing system for that matter.
I was working with my tutorials from class. When I tried to build using catkin_make, I encountered an error.
Since I have never worked with ROS before, I don't understand what the error log says, thus have no idea what the root of the error is.
Could someone kindly tell me why the error has occurred and how could I solve it?

Here's the error that occurs.

```
-- ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
-- ~~  traversing 5 packages in topological order:
-- ~~  - beginner_tutorials
-- ~~  - daisya_euslisp_tutorials
-- ~~  - dynamixel_7dof_arm
-- ~~  - turtleboteus
-- ~~  - dxl_armed_turtlebot
-- ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
-- +++ processing catkin package: 'beginner_tutorials'
-- ==> add_subdirectory(beginner_tutorials)
[roseus.camke] Loading... PROJECT_NAME=beginner_tutorials USE_ROSBILD=
-- Using these message generators: gencpp;geneus;genlisp;genpy
CMake Error at /opt/ros/hydro/share/catkin/cmake/assert.cmake:20 (message):
  

  Assertion failed: file
  '/home/mechuser/catkin_ws/src/beginner_tutorials/action/DoDishes.action'
  does not exist.  Message: action file not found

Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /opt/ros/hydro/share/actionlib_msgs/cmake/actionlib_msgs-extras.cmake:35 (assert_file_exists)
  beginner_tutorials/CMakeLists.txt:66 (add_action_files)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
make: *** [cmake_check_build_system] エラー 1
Invoking "make cmake_check_build_system" failed
```

Thanks in advanced for you help.
Shirish

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/201841/could-you-please-help-me-understand-the-error-log?/) by [ShirishDROS](https://answers.ros.org/users/21495/shirishdros/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2015-01-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This error is telling you that the file `/home/mechuser/catkin_ws/src/beginner_tutorials/action/DoDishes.action` doesn't exist. Does it? If it does, are the permissions correct (owned by you)?

---

Originally posted by [Dan Lazewatsky](https://answers.ros.org/users/173/dan-lazewatsky/) with karma: 9115 on 2015-01-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0